# "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" when dispatching action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Following the [example](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#async-action-creators) provided by the Redux docs I have setup my action creator as so:

```
export function createAlbumType(props) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch({
      type: CREATE_ALBUM_TYPE_REQUEST,
    });

    axios.post(`${ALBUM_TYPES_URL}`, props).then(
      response => dispatch({
        type: CREATE_ALBUM_TYPE_SUCCESS,
        response,
      }),
      error => dispatch({
        type: CREATE_ALBUM_TYPE_FAILURE,
        error,
      })
    );
  };
}
```

After my album type is successfully saved I'd like to simply redirect the user back to the index page. Unfortunately I'm not getting a promise back after dispatching. Based on my code, what seems to be the problem? I'm using `redux-thunk` as my middleware and `react-redux-router` for routing.

```
  onCreateSubmit(values) {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;

    return dispatch(createAlbumType(values))
      .then((action) => {
        if (action.type === 'CREATE_ALBUM_TYPE_SUCCESS') {
          dispatch(push('/album_types'));
        }
      });
  }
```

---

```
const store = createStore(reducers, {}, compose(
    applyMiddleware(
      routerMiddleware(browserHistory), 
      thunkMiddleware
    ),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
  )
);

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={ store } >
    <Router history={ history } routes={ routes } />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redux action is not returning a promise. You should return the axios.post function.

```
export function createAlbumType(props) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch({
      type: CREATE_ALBUM_TYPE_REQUEST,
    });

    return axios.post(`${ALBUM_TYPES_URL}`, props).then(
      response => dispatch({
        type: CREATE_ALBUM_TYPE_SUCCESS,
        response,
      }),
      error => dispatch({
        type: CREATE_ALBUM_TYPE_FAILURE,
        error,
      })
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend against doing this:

```
return dispatch(createAlbumType(values))
  .then((action) => {
    if (action.type === 'CREATE_ALBUM_TYPE_SUCCESS') {
      dispatch(push('/album_types'));
    }
  });
}
```

You're reinventing the reducer here with this `if (action.type)`. You should dispatch from within your `createAlbumType` action, inside the `.post().then()`. This way everything is contained where it should be.

Comment: Are you suggesting that you put the `push` method in the action creator?

Comment: Are you doing anything else with the `CREATE_ALBUM_TYPE_SUCCESS` action? Maybe you can just call `dispatch(push('/album_types'));` inside the `.then(`.

Comment: I think I follow you but for further clarification would you be able to provide a full example?